# How to use partitionBy function in window scala/spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns, `index` and `values`. I want to get the `delayValues` based on column `values`.

This is my code:

```
 val arr = Array(1,4,3,2,5,7,3,5,4,18)
    val input=new ArrayBuffer[(Int,Int)]()
    for(i<-0 until 10){
      input.append((i,arr(i)))
    }
    val window=Window.rowsBetween(-2,0)
    val df = sc.parallelize(input, 4).toDF("index","values")
    df.withColumn("valueDealy",first(col("values")).over(window)).show()
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is my expected result, but I find the all of data is collected into one partition, then I use `partitionBy` function, this is my changed code:

```
val arr = Array(1,4,3,2,5,7,3,5,4,18)
    val input=new ArrayBuffer[(Int,Int)]()
    for(i<-0 until 10){
      input.append((i,arr(i)))
    }
    val window=Window.orderBy(col("index")).partitionBy(col("index")).rowsBetween(-2,0)
    val df = sc.parallelize(input, 4).toDF("index","values")
    df.withColumn("valueDealy",first(col("values")).over(window)).show()
```

The result is:

```
+-----+------+----------+
|index|values|valueDealy|
+-----+------+----------+
|    0|     1|         1|
|    3|     2|         2|
|    7|     5|         5|
|    9|    18|        18|
|    4|     5|         5|
|    6|     3|         3|
|    5|     7|         7|
|    2|     3|         3|
|    1|     4|         4|
|    8|     4|         4|
+-----+------+----------+
```

I get the wrong result when I use `partitionBy`, what should I do? Thanks!

My expected output is:

```
        +-----+------+----------+
        |index|values|valueDealy|
        +-----+------+----------+
        |    0|     1|         1|
        |    1|     4|         1|
        |    2|     3|         1|
        |    3|     2|         4|
        |    4|     5|         3|
        |    5|     7|         2|
        |    6|     3|         5|
        |    7|     5|         7|
        |    8|     4|         3|
        |    9|    18|         5|
        +-----+------+----------+
```

and the data is in multiple partitions!

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I have changed my question @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no efficient solution which can be expressed directly with Spark SQL alone. Personally, when using Scala, I'd use `mllib` functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val n = 2
spark.createDataFrame(
  df.rdd.sliding(n + 1).map { xs  => Row(xs(0), xs(n)) },
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("delay", df.schema), StructField("current", df.schema))))
```

but if your dataset contains consecutive ids, you can also `join`:

```scala
df.alias("current").join(
  df.withColumn("index", $"index" - n).alias("previous"), Seq("index"))
```

Please not that both solutions may require some corrections at the beginning / end of the series. With `join` you can use `outer` join, with `sliding` you can `union` with required number of records at the beginning / end of the dataset.